# Remove __typename for specific query

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-apollo, apollo-client, subgraph

I am using `@apollo/client` and querying the graph protocol in my app. All of the queries are working well with the `__typename` except for the `_meta` query that's not using the `__typename` field.
So I am getting this error from that query - `Null value resolved for non-null field '__typename'`.

I've tried many solutions but none of them did the trick in my case.

First of all, if I set `addTypename` to false, then the `_meta` query is working but the caching doesn't work properly for other queries that are using the `__typename` field.
I've tried to use a middleware to omit the `__typename` field for that specific query but strangely I couldn't find any `__typename` key/value from the operation/context objects.
I've also tried to set the `addTypename` to false in the cache config of the context from the middleware but it didn't work.

```
const cleanTypeName = new ApolloLink(
    (operation: Operation, forward: NextLink) => {
        if (operation.operationName === "_meta") {
            if (operation.variables) {
                const omitTypename = (key, value) =>
                    key === "__typename" ? undefined : value
                operation.variables = JSON.parse(
                    JSON.stringify(operation.variables),
                    omitTypename
                )
            }

            const context = operation.getContext()
            operation.setContext({
                ...context,
                cache: {
                    ...context.cache,
                    addTypename: false,
                    config: {
                        ...context.cache.config,
                        addTypename: false,
                    },
                },
            })
        }

        return forward(operation)
    }
)
```

Actually, if I check via `console.log` the `operation.variables` was empty as the `_meta` query does not require any parameters to pass.

Comment: what kind of GraphQL server are u using?

Comment: I am calling this - https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2.
There's the _meta query which doesn't use __typename.